# got a Parse error webform.install in drupal 7

Tags: webforms

Hello guys i have got an parse error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in /sites/all/modules/webform.install on line 1917 what i suppose to do please help me out this trouble. Due to this i am hot able to install any module or access my site.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in eAccelerator, which has been (apparently) been fixed. Webform requires PHP 5.3. The affected version of eAccelerator doesn't support all of PHP 5.3 -- specifically anonymous functions.

eAccelerator is not a "default setting" of a server. It is add-on software (presumably added by a host company, and not kept up-to-date).

you can follow this [link](https://www.drupal.org/node/2467239) on drupal website which touch the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Someone/something has inserted a syntax error in the webform.install file. If the webform module isn't installed, remove it and download a new version that doesn't have the syntax error.